# django - If I change a field from ForeignKey to OneToOneField are there any database changes?

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django project I want to change a model field from `ForeignKey` to `OneToOneField`.

If I do that are there any database changes that I have to make?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) (emphasis added)

> A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a ForeignKey **with unique=True**, but the "reverse" side of the relation will directly return a single object.

Comment: In other words, the only thing that changes is a unique constraint is added to the column in your table. You'll need to manually update your table with the necessary SQL or use something like South to generate a migration.

Comment: Thank you Chris. That'a what I needed to know.